# Bootstrap modal remote with ZeroClipboard

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap-3, zeroclipboard

Im using twitter bootstrap 3.0s modal view to show an html
which has zerclipboard implemented. [https://github.com/zeroclipboard/ZeroClipboard]

This html has a button on click of which certain content is supposed to be copied to the clipboard via zeroclipboard.

```
ZeroClipboard.setDefaults({
    moviePath : '../js/lib/ZeroClipboard.swf',
    hoverClass : "zeroclipboard-is-hover", // The class used to hover over the object
    activeClass : "zeroclipboard-is-active",
});

var clip = new ZeroClipboard($('#btn-copy-cb'));

clip.on('dataRequested', function(client, args) {
    clip.setText($("#text-code").text());
});

clip.setHandCursor(true);
```

The html by itself works fine. but when it is called via the modal view as

```
$('#my-modal').modal({
    show: false,
    remote: "copytoclipboard.html"
});
```

Gives me an error when ever i hover on the button or click on it.

```
TypeError: this.htmlBridge is undefined


...e._singleton},p.detectFlashSupport=function(){var a=!1;if("function"==typeof Act...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set zerclip board after your modal content has load:

```
$('#my-modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {

var clip = new ZeroClipboard($('#btn-copy-cb'));

clip.on('dataRequested', function(client, args) {
    clip.setText($("#text-code").text());
});

clip.setHandCursor(true);

});
```

When remote URL is provided, content will be loaded via [jQuery's load.](http://api.jquery.com/load/) Cause the loading is asynchronous, you also could try to overwrite this and add "complete".